# Visual Studio - typescript project code metrics

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I create application in TypeScript and I would like to know how many lines of code I wrote. How would I calculate it in Visual Studio 2015 (Community). Code metrics are much more less function than in C# solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I found one simple solution:

In solution property check **Combine Javascript output into file**, then place filename and that's all. Save project and when file will be generated, open it by some text editor (for example notepad++).